# How to solve $\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^{-j}$?

Tags: summation, geometric-progressions

So, I'm trying to solve this sum :

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^{-j}$$

How should I proceed when I have $\sum_i a^{-i}$ ?

Comment: $2^{-j}=(\frac{1}{2})^j$.

Comment: Geometric progression

Comment: We don't _solve_ sums. We _evaluate_ or _compute_ them.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use the fact that

$$a^{-i}=\left(\frac 1a\right)^i.$$

Comment: Oh yes, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You sum is an "incomplete" (in the sense that the index does not go up to infinity) geometric series.
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{k-1} 2^{-j} = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} (\frac{1}{2})^j
$$
You can then use the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).